# Passing a parameter to a block stored inside an array of blocks

Tags: objective-c, ios, objective-c-blocks

I have this declared on the interface

```
void (^ soc)(NSString *type, BOOL configured);
```

and

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL serviceOK;
```

Then inside a method on .m I have this:

```
soc = ^(NSString *type, BOOL configured){
    // ...
};

// other blocks defined here
```

And then this:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayBlocks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                               [block1 copy],
                               [soc(typeOne, self.serviceOK) copy],
                               [block3 copy],
                               [block4 copy],
                               nil];
```

I have an error on the soc line with the message **bad receiver type void** (what ???)

If I simply run this:

```
soc(typeOne, self.serviceOK);
```

it works fine, but if I include it in the array it complains. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add a copy of the block then add:

```
[soc copy],
```

to the array. What you are trying to do is add a copy of the result of calling the block.

Answer (score 1):

```
soc(typeOne, self.serviceOK)
```

executes the block. and as it is returning nothing, there is nothing to send the copy message to and put into the array.